# I can't install PyInstaller , Preparing wheel metadata ... error

Tags: python, cmd, pip, pyinstaller, python-wheel

I am using Python 3.9.1 (12/31/2020,downloaded from microsoft store) and I want to turn one of my projects into an executable but every time I try to `pip install pyinstaller` it says this (I have cut some of the code in the beginning because other than it having no error stackoverflow says my post is mostly code):

```
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\37A0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwurr1dm8'
     cwd: C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-gbhcr_je
Complete output (34 lines):
Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
running dist_info
creating C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info
writing C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing entry points to C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
writing requirements to C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
writing top-level names to C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
warning: no files found matching 'pyinstaller-gui.py'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory 'doc'
no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
creating 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-61iwlidj\pyinstaller.dist-info'
error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\37A0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpwurr1dm8' Check the logs for full command output.
```

and when i pip install wheel it says:

```
     Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\γιώργος 
βέβας\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local- 
packages\python39\site-packages (0.36.2)
```

Also when i upgraded pip this showed up:

```
 WARNING: The scripts pip.exe, pip3.9.exe and pip3.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\Γιώργος Βέβας\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
```

Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

Answer (score 0):

Try with another version of Python. I had the same error using 3.9.0, but it worked great when I started using 3.8.5 instead.

Comment: I tried it with 3.8.7 but it still didnt work. On another note i tried downloading pygame and it showed no problems , thanks for answering though,

Comment: welcome! Thanks for appreciating my answer